# How to add tooltip to a svg in javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg, tooltip

I have a menu with svg elements and I can drag and drop them on a container. What I want is to add a tooltip for each svg element so the user, when hovers the svg, knows what drops on container. My js code is a s follows:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var shapesGroupName = 'editor.shapeSVG'; // used to organize and gropping the shapes, displayed in editor menu as label with expand/collapse 
    var typeId = 'proceng';          // used to identify shapes type

    var shapes = [
        {
            name: 'SVG1', ico: 'MyPath/SVG1.svg', content: [
                { id: '', type: 'path', attr: { d: 'M0,0h90' } },   
                { id: '', type: 'path', attr: { d: 'M0,22.5h22.51' } },   
                etc...        
            ]
        }, 
        {
            name: 'SVG2', ico: 'MyPath/SVG2.svg', content: [
                { id: '', type: 'path', attr: { d: 'M14,14 l200,0' } },   
                { id: '', type: 'path', attr: { d: 'M14,64 l50,0' } }, 
                etc...
            ]
        },  
        {
            name: 'SVG3', ico: 'MyPath/SVG3.svg', content: [
                { id: '', type: 'path', attr: { d: 'M27,27 l126,0' } },   
                { id: '', type: 'path', attr: { d: 'M22,72 l50,0' } },  
                 etc...
            ]
        }];

    // merge shapes groups        
    for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
        shapes[i].name = typeId + '-' + shapes[i].name;
    }
    if (svgEditor.shapesGrps[shapesGroupName]) {
        for (var i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
            svgEditor.shapesGrps[shapesGroupName].push(shapes[i]);
        }
    } else {
        svgEditor.shapesGrps[shapesGroupName] = shapes;
    }
}());
```

[image]

So when the user covers the icon SVG3, a tooltip to be displayed with text "MySVG3". How could I do it?